# SPO - Unable to copy/move document set to another library on the same site

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-set, copy, move-to

I'm unable to move and/or copy Document sets from a library to another library on the same site. When I select Move-To/Copy-To the current library is selected automatically and I'm unable to select another library.

How it looks:

[image]

If I test on a normal folder in the same library:

[image]

The library is quite large ~50000 files and a size of ~40 GB. The average Document set is between 200 to 500 MB. I've created a couple of views that narrows the items down to 100 to 200 items that I want to copy, however that does not help.

What could be restricting the possibility to copy these Document sets to another library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, it's by design that we cannot move/copy document sets to other libraries directly. You could vote on uservoice: https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/37773979-modern-document-sets-moving-and-copying

As a workaround, you could first copy/move your DS in a folder and then you copy/move the folder in the destination library. From the destination library you copy/move the DS where you want and you delete the folder.